# Bug in Reputation History: Accepted edited posts don't have any +2 reputation points

Tags: bug, reputation, reputation-history

Yesterday (30 Jul 2020) I have edited four posts, and then I would have +8 reputation points, but when I open the reputation history, I can't see any +2 of four edited posts.

I think that is a bug, because yesterday I also didn't see some accepted editing reviews in the reputation history, but they are in *All actions* → *Suggestions* (I forgot to take a screenshot), but some hours after I have seen four accepted editing reviews in the reputation history.

[image]

Comment: You don't earn rep from suggested edits after gaining 1000 rep.

Comment: @Samuel Liew: Except for suggested tag wiki edits (below 5,000 reputation points, and either above 1 or above 2,000 (I am not sure which one - I think it is 1)).

Comment: @PeterMortensen As far as I can remember, 1000 reputation earned is the limit for all edit types. I think you're confusing the 1k max with the 2k privilege for not needing to suggest edits on posts.